# Gateway-to-gateway VPN not allowing access to PDC/shares

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, file-sharing

I have a gateway-to-gateway VPN between my datacenter (HQ) and a remote site.  The VPN is between two Netgear UTM9S gateways.  In HQ, I have a Windows Server 2003 DC as well as several Windows 7 Pro workstations.  In the remote site I have two Windows 7 Pro workstations that used to live in HQ and connected just fine.  Pings work fine back and forth between the sites

The root issue is I am unable to access password protected shares on the DC from the remote site.  Further, I am unable to RDP from the remote site to any computer in HQ, where I can RDP from HQ to the remote site without issue.

I can browse shares on the DC (via its IP or FQDN), and can access the publically available ones like SYSVOL and NETLOGON.  But anything that was password protected, or, that I created to help troubleshoot, ends with the message "...is not accessible.   You might not have permissions to use this network resource... the specified network name is no longer available."

Below is an event log entry from the DC in HQ that I think is key to the issue, though I'm not sure what it may mean.

```
Event Type: Success Audit
Event Source: Security
Event Category: Logon/Logoff 
Event ID: 540
Date:  12/19/2012
Time:  9:59:29 AM
User:  EMR\itadmin
Computer: CEMSSV-01
Description:
Successful Network Logon:
  User Name: itadmin
  Domain:  EMR
  Logon ID:  (0x0,0x50DE76)
  Logon Type: 3
  Logon Process: NtLmSsp 
  Authentication Package: NTLM
  Workstation Name: EMRPC-01
  Logon GUID: -
  Caller User Name: -
  Caller Domain: -
  Caller Logon ID: -
  Caller Process ID: -
  Transited Services: -
  Source Network Address: 10.100.2.101
  Source Port: 0
```

Comment: As an aside: You don't have a Windows 2003 PDC. The concept of Primary Domain Controllers went away in Windows 2000.

Comment: Greg, in all seriousness, it would be great if you could shorten and re-format your question. I have a feeling most readers are skipping this question because it is so long.

Comment: Thanks, I did shorten into something that may be easier to consume.  Just wanted to be complete.